# How to choose a proper numerical optimisation method

Tags: monte-carlo, numerical-optimization, finite-differences

Given a problem in numerical analysis in finance/econometrics, how to decide whther to choose Monte Carlo, Newton Raphson , Finite Difference , Gradient descent?

I had this silly misconception that all these methods pretty much do the same thing by performing a series of substitutions and the only difference is in the rate of convergence. But I guess this is wrong. Hence I am asking how to deicde which method to use when?

Comment: Actually only one of these is a true optimization method : gradient descent. In a nutshell, Monte-Carlo is basically used to evaluate integrals using a randomized procedure ; Newton-Raphson is a numerical root-finding procedure ; Finite Difference is used to numerically approximate the solution to differential equations ; and Gradient descent is a generic optimization method,that can be used when you can compute gradients. It has two main variants : steepest gradient and conjugate gradient, often deemed to be more efficient.

Comment: However, Newton-Raphson **can** be used in optimization to find a point where the gradient is $0$.  When it works, it's often much more efficient than gradient descent.